# Internet Explorer and clip-path

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, svg

As far as I'm aware clip-path should work in IE, as demonstrated in many articles and this tutorial [CSS Masking](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/?redirect_from_locale=fr)

However I can't get the below to run properly on IE, but it works fine on Chrome.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 240px;
  height: 500px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}

.pentagon {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0px 0px, 100px 0px, 112px 13px, 240px 13px, 240px 250px, -250px 250px);
  -o-clip-path: polygon(0px 0px, 100px 0px, 112px 13px, 240px 13px, 240px 250px, -250px 250px);
  -ms-clip-path: polygon(0px 0px, 100px 0px, 112px 13px, 240px 13px, 240px 250px, -250px 250px);
  float: left;
}

.avatar {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

html {
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(white, #ddd);
}

h1,
p {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="avatar">
    <img class="pentagon" src="http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m5nre6cxkQ1qbs7p5o1_r1_500.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>

<svg>
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="pentagon" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <polygon points=".5,0 1,.30 .2,1 .2,1 0,.30" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: IE which version ? SVG is supported by IE9+.

Comment: It's IE9+, that's why I was surprised, it's supposed to work but no joy on my end.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

After more in depth research, when working with the image directly, IE supports clip as in rectangular shapes only but not clipPath complicated shapes.

My solution was to add the image to an SVG as below, and this time it works in both Chrome and IE9+.

[Demo JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f8tcxooy/)

```css
body {
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}

#image-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.svg-background,
.svg-image {
  clip-path: url(#clip-triangle);
}

.svg-image {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease 0.2s;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0.2s;
}

svg.clip-svg {
  height: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 250px;
}

#svg-1 {
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="image-wrapper">
  <svg id="svg-1" class="clip-svg">
        <rect class='svg-background' width="300" height="300" fill="#ffffff" />
        <image id="img-1" class='svg-image' width="300" height="300" xlink:href="http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m5nre6cxkQ1qbs7p5o1_r1_500.jpg" />
    </svg>
</div>
<svg id="svg-defs">
    <defs>
        <clipPath id="clip-triangle">
            <polygon points="0 0, 100 0, 112 13, 240 13, 240 250, -250 250"/>
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: I made what I think is a more clear fork of this answer: https://jsfiddle.net/2wu0dwrL/

Comment: But it seem it will not work if the image is with responsive size. Right?

Comment: Does this work on Apple and iOs devices? My research says no: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path

Comment: It works on iOS 11, Windows 10 / IE 11, Chrome 87, FF 76.0.1

Answer (score -1):

Look at this [Demo JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rnt3Lu0p/) it supports responsive image and well documented

```css
    .member-picture {
      width: 200px; /*Final image width*/
    }
    
    .member-picture image{
      width:100%; /*for responsive image behaviour*/
      clip-path: url('#small-clip');
    }
```

```html
  <svg class="member-picture">
      <image xlink:href="https://via.placeholder.com/350x200"></image>
  </svg>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 250.35696 212.65134"> <!--viewBox = "X1 Y1 X2 Y2"-->
    <defs>
      <clipPath id="small-clip" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox"
                  transform="scale(.0039 .0047)">
                  <!--Use clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox" and transform="scale(1/(viewBox.X2-viewBox.X1) 1/(viewBox.Y2-viewBox.Y1)" -->
        <path      d="M231.76,2.10959c5.989,1.0033,11.34394,3.5405,14.95847,9.74636,5.229,8.97779,3.54658,20.83845,2.65967,30.67514-4.2102,46.31217-8.047,92.66163-12.03267,138.993A28.82369,28.82369,0,0,1,235.49314,189.8c-2.913,7.28451-8.96608,11.54254-17.95131,14.28814-10.36022,3.16575-21.42435,3.0895-32.14721,3.458L40.64126,212.52043c-7.4331.25543-15.17585,0.4528-21.94517-2.62817C9.79852,205.84265,4.11114,196.65751,1.7732,187.16541S-0.05058,167.74594.329,157.97752c1.53266-39.43778.62959-78.92331,0.4924-118.39062C0.7836,28.70009,1.2929,16.57391,9.01875,8.9034,20.99475-2.98675,42.47458.45166,57.6212,0.4913q29.26963,0.07661,58.5389.24813,48.42851,0.2838,96.855.82742C219.161,1.63584,225.777,1.1073,231.76,2.10959Z"
              fill="#4d4d4d">  
        </path>
      </clipPath>
    </defs>
  </svg>
```