# Cutting image diagonally with CSS

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

**How to cut away part of an image or container diagonally using CSS?**

The part that needs to be cut away has the form of a triangle

[image: Example of image]

To be more specific: if the above picture is the image the blue part should be cut out, not the yellow

The html should be:

```
<figure>
 <img src="img_pulpit.jpg" alt="The Pulpit Rock">
</figure>
```

or:

```
<div class="container">
  content
</div>
```

There is from my own investigation a lot of ways to do this, but most of them is hacky, so looking for a best approach

Min browser support: IE11, latest webkits etc.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use CSS3 `-clip-path` and `polygon` like this. You can specify whatever path you want to.

```css
img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0 100px, 100px 80px, 100px 0);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0 100px, 100px 80px, 100px 0);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/0/100/100">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r3p9ph5k/

For some extra bits you might want to take a look at e.g. [this](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/). Also, for more information about IE, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21904672/internet-explorer-and-clip-path).

Comment: Best solution if [IE support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path) is not needed.

Comment: Thank you, based on your answer I think something like this is the best solution for my specific problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/r3p9ph5k/1/

Comment: [tbh clip-path hasn't really become highly supported yet - even with chrome/firefox having only limited support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path)

Comment: No IE and no Edge support, it's still too early to use it.

Answer (score 13):

You could use a `pseudo element`, combined with `overflow:hidden;`

**Result**

[image]

```css
div {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: url(http://placekitten.com/g/300/300);
}
div:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 93%;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 150%;
  background: red;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-5deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-5deg);
  transform: rotate(-5deg);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: This should be the selected answer because it is intuitively easier to change than @Roope's response

Answer (score 6):

This one is a little bit dirty but... Here is the idea :

**HTML**:

```css
body {
  background: #eee;
}
figure {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 20px;
  margin-left: -20px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  margin-right: -20px;
  height: 200px;
  transform: rotate(-10deg);
}
figure img {
  transform: rotate(10deg);
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/560/300" />
</figure>
```

Note: Another method could be using a pseudo-element to mask the picture, but this will not produce a real "cut" where you should be able to see through.

Answer (score 1):

-You can use http://cssplant.com/clip-path-generator for this.

It's just a "dirty solution", the best way is placing a svg above the img.

Maybe in a future, the "clip css property" would support another kind of shapes than just "rect" and things like this could be done!

Another "dirty way" is putting a div above the img, with the background-color that you want and rotate it!

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea:

**HTML**

```
<figure>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" alt="">
</figure>
```

**CSS**

```
figure {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 0;
}

figure:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 200%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -91%;
    background: red;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(355deg);
    transform: rotate(355deg);
}
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/a9o5cmag/)