# How to diagonally split an html element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm wondering what would be the best method of diagonally splitting an element, so that it looks like the image below, using any means of html/css/js? The images shouldn't be modified, but rather just masked.

[image]

I tried doing with skew, but that unfortunately distorts the image. I can't really figure out a structure that can be reused with varying length of text.

Comment: Please show us code that you have tried so far?

Comment: Wrap image in a div element and then skew this div element;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve that by overlapping 2 divs and skew one of them, like how I did in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/s0h2g0zw/

```
#parallelogram {
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
    -webkit-transform: skew(20deg);
       -moz-transform: skew(20deg);
         -o-transform: skew(20deg);
    background: red;
}

#square {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
  position:absolute;
  left:0px;


}
```

You may want to look more on other examples : https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Hope this will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use skew on div text with background color and positionning image under the div with  z-index ?

Answer (score 0):

Masking an image diagonally has been answered here: 
[Cutting image diagonally with CSS3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29259935/cutting-image-diagonally-with-css3)

Here they used clip-path instead of one div masking the other. 

Which could then be overlayed a div for the text.

But then keep in mind how this will look in a responsive design.