# How could I divide two div like this?

Tags: html, css, material-ui, css-selectors, tailwind-css

How Could I divide two div Like this.
Is it Possible with TailwindCSS.
Also what can be the code if I divide this two div with CSS.

[image: Image show the problem of div divider]

I'm sucking with this also I can imagine how it is possible.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to diagonally split an html element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38617465/how-to-diagonally-split-an-html-element)

Comment: Another possibility: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38142498/split-div-with-diagonal-line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this

```html
  <div class="relative flex h-20 w-full items-center justify-between overflow-hidden border-2 border-gray-500">  <!-- manually set height -->
    <div class="flex h-full flex-grow items-center">content 1</div>
    <div class="h-24 rotate-[30deg] transform border-2 border-gray-500"></div> <!-- manually set divider height -->
    <div class="flex h-full flex-grow items-center">content 2</div>
  </div>
```

[image: example implementation]

You could change the `flex-grow` class and give `w-1/2`, `w-1/3`&`2/3` to classes if you want to control the ratios.

Additionally `pl-10`, `pr-10` etc could be given to the content divs if the slanted line is crossing into actual content.