# How to resize SVG clip-path to be same size as image

Tags: html, css, svg, clip-path

I've got little problem resizing my svg clip-path to fit the image size.

I've got code like this:

```
<svg id="image-svg" class="clip">
     <img class="main-img" src="http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m5nre6cxkQ1qbs7p5o1_r1_500.jpg" alt="" />
</svg>
<svg class="clip">
     <clipPath id="clipPolygon">
          <polygon points="52 0,100 45,50 100,0 50">
          </polygon>
     </clipPath>
</svg>
```

And then i'm using css like this:

```
#image-svg {
  left:0;
  top:0;
}
.main-img {
  clip-path: url('#clipPolygon');
  width:90%;
}
```

Everything works fine, except the clip-path is much smaller then image itself. How to fix this? Here is my working fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/7egbccpw/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution is to specify the path directly with CSS and use % for the values

```css
.main-img {
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 45%, 50% 100%, 0 50%);
}
```

```html
<img class="main-img" src="https://lorempixel.com/200/200/" alt="" />
<img class="main-img" src="https://lorempixel.com/100/100/" alt="" />
<img class="main-img" src="https://lorempixel.com/50/50/" alt="" />
```

Comment: yes i know it works, but i need solution also for IE so i cannot use clip-path in CSS

Comment: yes, but as far as i know it should work in IE:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21904672/internet-explorer-and-clip-path

Comment: @user3267302 and what if you try my code by adding the img inside an SVG .. as i simplified the code

Comment: I meant in my example is not :) i removed the SVG to simplify code ... so did you try my clip path with an image inside SVG

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, your example is broken because there is no `<img>` element in SVGs. You want the `<image>` element.

```css
#image-svg {
  left:0;
  top:0;
}
.main-img {
  clip-path: url('#clipPolygon');
  width:90%;
}
```

```html
<svg id="image-svg" class="clip">
  <image class="main-img" xlink:href="http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m5nre6cxkQ1qbs7p5o1_r1_500.jpg" alt="" />
</svg>

<svg class="clip">
  <clipPath id="clipPolygon">
    <polygon points="52 0,100 45,50 100,0 50"></polygon>
  </clipPath>
</svg>
```

Now I presume you mean you want the clip path to *automatically* fit the image size. Otherwise I am guessing you would have just made the clip path coordinates bigger.

The way you do that in SVG is to use `objectBoundingBox` coordinates. When objectBoundingBox coordinate mode in in effect, coordinates are scaled so that (0,0) represents the top left of the target element, and (1,1) represents the bottom right of the target element. In this case, the target element is the image.

For use this mode for clip paths, you need to set `clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox"`. Then you just need to scale all your polygon coordinate values so that the are between 0 and 1.

```css
#image-svg {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
.main-img {
  clip-path: url('#clipPolygon');
  width:90%;
  height: 90%;
}
```

```html
<svg id="image-svg" class="clip">
  <image class="main-img" xlink:href="http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m5nre6cxkQ1qbs7p5o1_r1_500.jpg" alt="" />
</svg>

<svg class="clip">
  <clipPath id="clipPolygon" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
    <polygon points="0.52 0 1 0.45 0.5 1 0 0.5"></polygon>
  </clipPath>
</svg>
```