# Clip and Clip path not working in IE 11

Tags: css

I am trying to make this in CSS.

[image]

But this is how it renders in IE11.
[image]

My code below works in Chrome, but not in IE 11.  "www.CanIUse.com" says the clip rule works in IE11.  What is wrong with my CSS?

```css
body{margin: 50px;}

        .bracket-container {
            position: relative;
            border: 0px solid green;
            width: 25px;
            height: 58px;
            width: 25px;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }

        #square-clip{
            width: 24px;
            height: 50px;
            background: none;
            border: 4px solid red;
            border-left: 0;
            border-radius: 8px;        
            clip: (0, 0,0, 25px);
            position: absolute;
            left:0;
        }

        #triangle-right {
            width: 0;
            height: 0;
            border-top: 8px solid transparent;
            border-left: 10px solid red;
            border-bottom: 8px solid transparent;
            position: absolute;
            right:-12px;
            top: 21px;
        }
```

```html
  <h3>Using the new CSS Clip-path</h3>
    https://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path</br>
    <div class="bracket-container">
        <div id="triangle-right"></div>
        <div id="square-clip-path"></div>
    </div>


    <div class="bracket-container">
        <div id="triangle-right"></div>
        <div id="square-clip"></div>
   </div>
```

Comment: I've edited your post as a snippet, so it's easier for us to check out. You were missing the CSS declarations for the #square-clip-path... but anyway, your clip solution works perfectly fine on IE, Chrome, etc https://jsfiddle.net/Ls7zqv0u/

Comment: Clip path doesn't seem to be supported in css in ie11, but you can use a simple svg as a background image, or as @FacundoCorradini mentions, the "good ol' borders triangle technique"

Comment: @admcfajn, what is the good ol' triangle technique?

Comment: @ryanjohnsond i'm quoting the answer [... then a pseudo element for the triangle with the good ol' borders triangle technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48453214/2510939). I had run into this exact problem a couple days ago & wasn't able to find any way to get a `clip-path` css declaration working in IE, but it seems `clipPath` in an svg-element could be a work-around https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21904672/internet-explorer-and-clip-path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use clip at all, nor multiple divs.

Use just one, adjust the borders as needed for the bracket body, then a pseudo element for the triangle with the good ol' borders triangle technique

```css
.bracket{
  border: 4px solid red;
  width:100px; height:150px;
  border-left:none;
  border-radius:0 10% 10% 0; 
  position:relative;
}

.bracket::after{
  content:"";
  width:20px; height:20px;
  position:absolute; 
  left:100%;
  top:50%; transform:translateY(-50%);
  box-sizing:border-box;
  border-top:15px solid transparent;
  border-bottom:15px solid transparent;
  border-left:15px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="bracket"> </div>
```

Comment: Thank you! That's great.

Comment: It's been awhile. Where do I do that?

Comment: @ryanjohnsond To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Comment: Accepted. Thnx again! Is there a way to get the height to transform by percent instead of px?

Comment: yup, just use % height on the .bracket class

Comment: That's because the snippet has no parents with a declared height, so 20% of zero makes zero height. Declare the height of a parent element (or HTML, body height 100%) and it will work