# Create angled triangle top and bottom of page

Tags: css, google-maps, html5-canvas, maps

I'm trying to create a diagonal div with SVG and I'm having a lot of issues. 
My goal is:

1. Create full-width map on the top left corner.
2. Create full-width div of text on the bottom right corner.

I have worked on it but the SVG div overlapping the map and I can't select map and if I position map higher than SVG than map overlaps entire page.

You can see in the image what I want to achieve should look like.

[image: preview]

Comment: Please share the code as well. Try to put a demo.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `clip-path` to do the job. AFAIK it's the only think able to achieve desired effect without JS and **without assumption, that rectangle with map is a square**. [Support, unfortunately, isn't perfect](https://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path). I also found [interesting creator for clip paths](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/).

#### [More about `clip-path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path)

> The clip-path CSS property creates a clipping region that defines what part of an element should be displayed. More specifically, those portions that are inside the region are shown, while those outside are hidden.

Unfortunetely it doesn't work on IE, but [here you can find some fallback workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21904672/internet-explorer-and-clip-path).

#### Snippet

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  background: black;
}

.map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 0% 100%, 0 0);
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 0% 100%, 0 0);
}

.corner {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="map"></div>
  <div class="corner"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks it worked..but unfortunately it's not supporting in IE :(

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not, but [here you can look into some tricks to make it work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21904672/internet-explorer-and-clip-path). If you **do not** know dimensions of rectangle that needs to be clipped I see no other solution. However if you do know them then there are few other tricks I may suggest.